# Are there any NP-complete for continuous mathematics?

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete

Looking at this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems), it seems most NP-complete problems are based on discrete structures, such as graphs. What are some problems that involve real or complex analysis instead of discrete analysis? If none, why not?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I think that (i) problems on discrete structures are often real everyday problems (e.g. TSP, knapsack, ...) so they often have real-life applications (ii) there are enough troubles with discrete structures and switching to real analysis often means dealing not only with "hardness" but also with "uncomputability" . BTW there is surely some research on the topic; see for example [A simple introduction to computable analysis](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/resources/pdf/ica.pdf) (which became a [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540668176) in 2000) ...

Comment: ... A simple problem example is: "[Is the Mandelbrot set decidable?](http://www.netbased-university.de/imperia/md/content/fakultaetfuermathematikundinformatik/forschung/berichte/bericht_298.pdf)" (there are several nonequivalent computability notions over the real or complex numbers, so the answer may be positive in one model, negative in another)

Comment: See Ker-I Ko's book/papers on complexity theory of real fictions.

Comment: @Kaveh, in the spirit of Borges and Lem?

Comment: @András, not familiar with that. I am referring e.g. to this book: https://books.google.ca/books?id=QJnVBwAAQBAJ

Comment: @Kaveh: just riffing on your "real fictions"...